# how to change the IP address in the url

Tags: python, url, request, arguments, ip

how to change the ip address in the url.

requests.get('http://192.168.200.10:5525/system.cgi')

I try this code but nothing comes outtrybut nothes o

```
import requests
from secimc import password

ipaddr = '192.168.100.115'

resp = requests.get('http://ipaddr:5525/system.cgi')
```

Comment: Please add more details. Did some error appear? If yes add it to your question, if not add desired output and actual output

Answer (score 1):

should work just fine

```
import requests
from sec import password

ipaddr = '192.168.100.115'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0',
    'Authorization': password,
}

params = (
    ('time', '66'),
)

resp = requests.get('http://'+ipaddr+':5525/system.cgi', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `ipaddr` in the url is just a part of the string. To use it as variable try to use f-string:

```py
resp = requests.get(f'http://{ipaddr}:5525/system.cgi', headers=headers, params=params)
```